# bxslider stacked before pageload

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bxslider

I am using bx-slider and facing a problem that on pageload images of slider are not loading perfectly. All I want that images should be fully load on page load or load after complete page load, or images will hide until page not fully loaded.
here is java script code

```
 $(window).load(function () { 
var $heroSlides = $('.hero-slider ul.bxslider > li');
        if ($heroSlides.length > 1) {
            var slider = $('.hero-slider .bxslider').bxSlider({
                responsive: true,
                auto: true,
                pause: 5000,
                controls: false,
                autoHover: true,
                mode: 'fade'
            });
        }
 });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this -
Update your css and hide slider outer `DIV`

```
.hero-slider {
display:none;
}
```

and then show it just before slider call in your script.

```
     $(window).load(function () { 
    $('.hero-slider').show();
    var $heroSlides = $('.hero-slider ul.bxslider > li');
            if ($heroSlides.length > 1) {
                var slider = $('.hero-slider .bxslider').bxSlider({
                    responsive: true,
                    auto: true,
                    pause: 5000,
                    controls: false,
                    autoHover: true,
                    mode: 'fade'
                });
            }
     });
```

Try with `document.ready` if `window.load` does not work.